# Macbook 2015, 8,1 -- how to get the keyboard and trackpad working with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, touchpad, macbook

Are there any instructions how to install the keyboard and trackpad when using Ubuntu 18.04 on a Macbook?

I've tried searching and I get a lot of Macbook Pro or other strange answers.

The recommended answer for 16.04 indicates that kernel 4.14 solved the issue, however 18.04 uses kernel 4.15

Comment: Did you try installing https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Macbook (12' 2015) keyboard and trackpad](/q/1003055/175814) you need an out-of-tree device driver (at least until one lands in the mainline Linux kernel). The answer to that question indicates that the installation of [*macbook12-spi-driver*](https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver#readme), which you don’t have yet, along with a kernel version ≥4.14, which you do have by default in Ubuntu 18.04, solves the issue.

## SPI Driver Installation

I’m going to line out how to install the “[input driver for the SPI keyboard / trackpad found on 12" MacBooks (2015 and later) and newer MacBook Pros (late 2016 and later)](https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver#readme)”.

### 1 Preparation

1. Make sure that Git, build tools, DKMS, and kernel headers are installed:

   ```sh
   sudo apt install git build-essential dkms linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)
   ```
2. Clone and enter the SPI driver source code repository:

   ```sh
   git clone https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver.git
   cd macbook12-spi-driver
   ```
3. Make sure that you don’t use the `noapic` boot option.

   If you’re unsure check the Grub configuration with:

   ```sh
   grep -e '^[^#]*noapic' /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/default/grub /etc/grub.d/*
   ```

   No match means no `noapic` option; but a match doesn’t mean that it’s actually enabled.

### 2 Installation

1. For the first time or whenever build issues occur you can test the build process:

   ```sh
   make
   ```

   To clean up the build result again:

   ```sh
   make clean
   ```
2. Register the kernel module source code with DKMS to handle the build and installation for *every new kernel version*:

   ```sh
   sudo dkms install -m applespi -v 0.1
   ```

   If the DKMS fails it will print an error message with the build log location that contains the actual error message.

### 3 Testing and configuration

1. Make sure that the kernel modules `spi_pxa2xx_platform`, `spi_pxa2xx_pci`<sup>1</sup>, and `intel_lpss_pci`<sup>2</sup> are loadable:

   ```sh
   sudo modprobe spi_pxa2xx_platform spi_pxa2xx_pci intel_lpss_pci
   ```

   No output means success.
2. Add the modules to the initial boot file system to have them available during boot password entry:

   ```sh
   sudo mkdir -p /etc/initramfs-tools/modules.d
   printf '%s\n' applespi spi_pxa2xx_platform spi_pxa2xx_pci intel_lpss_pci | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/modules.d/macbook12-spi
   ```

   You may skip the modules `spi_pxa2xx_pci`<sup>1</sup> or `intel_lpss_pci`<sup>2</sup> depending on their footnotes.

---

<sup>1</sup> Needed for 2015 Macbooks only.

<sup>2</sup> Needed for post-2015 Macbooks and all Macbook-Pros only.

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!